# Remove last border-bottom?

Tags: css, html-lists, border, css-selectors

I use li to show a list of records.

Each li has a bottom-border:1px solid black;

but I don't want to show border at the end of li?

example:

```
.test li{
        height:1%;
        overflow:hidden;
        padding:4px 0;
        margin:-1px 0 0;
        border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    }

.test li.last { border-bottom: none;  }

<ul class="test">
  <li> Foo 1 </li>
  <li> Foo 2 </li>
  <li> Foo 3 </li>
</ul>
```

Foo 3 still showing bottom border.

Comment: You are not giving the last LI a class `last`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can also set the top border instead and use the sibling selector to handle this without the need for an extra class:

```
.test li{
        height:1%;
        overflow:hidden;
        padding:4px 0;
        margin:-1px 0 0;
    }

.test li + li { border-top: 1px solid black;  }
```

Comment: Thank you, that does work but does that work? What is li + li?

Comment: @user, http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html E + F: Matches any F element immediately preceded by a sibling element E. In this case, it matches any li immediately preceded by an li.

Answer (score 23):

```
.test li{
        height:1%;
        overflow:hidden;
        padding:4px 0;
        margin:-1px 0 0;
        border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    }

.test li:last-child { border-bottom: none;  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Add a class to the li of last or if css3 is acceptable

ul.test>li:last-of-type {
  border-bottom:none
}

Answer (score 3):

you can use jquery too

```
$('ul li:last-child').css('border-bottom', 'none');
```

I prefer this way as it means less jumping around and crazy weird exceptions in your css.

Comment: :last-child is a great option, as it selects the last element for each parent. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Please add class to this :

`li:last-child { border-bottom: none; }`

Answer (score 0):

Using: `:last-of-type` with `:not()`

> The:last-of-type selector allows you to target the last occurrence of an element within its container. It is defined in the CSS Selectors Level 3 spec as a “structural pseudo-class”, meaning it is used to style content based on its relationship with parent and sibling content.

```css
.test li{
  height:1%;
  overflow:hidden;
  padding:4px 0;
  margin:-1px 0 0;  
}
.test li:not(:last-of-type) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<ul class="test">
  <li> Foo 1 </li>
  <li> Foo 2 </li>
  <li> Foo 3 </li>
</ul>
```

Article link: [enter link description here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/l/last-of-type/#:%7E:text=The%20%3Alast%2Dof%2Dtype,with%20parent%20and%20sibling%20content.)